# HTTPS + Express + Socket.io bug

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, https, server

I'm trying to integrate HTTPS, Express, and Socket.io together. It logs `server up and running at 8080 port`. However, whenever I access the website it doesn't even display `/public/index.html`. This program works when I change `require('https');` to `require('http')`, but I want HTTP*S*. I tried several different ports, 8080, 3000, 80, 8843, 443, they all don't work.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl.cert'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
const serverPort = 8080;

const server = https.createServer(options, app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection');
  socket.emit('message', 'This is a message from the dark side.');
});

server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', serverPort);
});
```

Comment: What *does* it display, what do the logs tell you?

Comment: It doesn't say anything after "server up and running at 8080 port", buy i still can't access the website. (im using REPLIT)

Comment: What does not being able to access the website mean? Error / error page / timeout / .... ?

Comment: Replit displays "Hmmmm.... We Couldn't Reach Your Repl
Make sure your repl has a port open and is ready to receive HTTP traffic." on my website

Comment: Trying to running https server on port 8080?  What exact URL are you trying to access the page with from the browser?

Comment: I'd suggest adding `server.on('error', err => { console.log(err)});` and see if it's logging anything wrong there.  Could be related to your https credentials too.

Comment: It doesn't log anything